# trying to open application with os.system() in python on mac says file doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I am trying to open the Music app on mac using os open on python but it says file doesn't exist

```
import os
os.system("open /Applications/Music.app");
```

Comment: @Jan this is true, but it can still be opened in this way. In this case, the location of the app was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**subprocess approach**

`os.systm()` is not the prefered way to execute programs in new `process`. use `subprocess` module. see documentation [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

```
import subprocess
cmd = "open /System/Applications/Music.app" # i guess its a shell command so argument shell must be true.
```

if you want to communicate with the process, use the `subprocess.PIPE`. if you dont need any communication, omit them from the function arguments.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr=p.communicate() #return a tuple of the stdout and stderr of the process.
```

Comment: This is a good point, even Python's own docs on [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) suggest using the `subprocess` module instead

Comment: @awarrier99 - thank you i have been use it for a while in my python scripts. its lack some timing (timeout process) ability but a good engineer can `inherits` from the `subprocess` class and expand its functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This application is actually located in `/System/Applications`, as are several other default Mac apps, so you should open it like this instead:

```
import os
os.system("open /System/Applications/Music.app")
```